# Should my nav tag be in my section tag?

Tags: html, nav

I'm new to this "semantic tagging". But I don't know if this is correct. In short, I don't know when to use the section vs the nav tags in this case. Should it be one or the other, none at all, or exactly as I have it? I'm speaking of the section with id = sidebar.

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <table id="formHeader" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="sidebar">
            @*<nav>*@
                Go To...
                <ul>
                    <li>First Move to Moon</li>
                    <li>First Move to Moon</li>                    
                </ul>
            @*</nav>*@   
        </section>
        <section id="main">        
            @RenderBody()                              
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The @* *@ is the ASP.NET MVC comment tag.

Answer (score 6):

You need to understand two things:

- Each sectioning content element (`section`, `article`, `aside`, `nav`) creates an entry in the document outline (play around with an outliner, for example [gsnedders HTML5 Outliner](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/)).
- In that sense, the `nav` belongs to its nearest parent sectioning content element, or the nearest parent sectioning root (like `body`).

So your example would create the following outline:

```
 1. (no heading) → body
   1.1 (no heading) → nav
   1.2 (no heading) → section (#sidebar)
     1.2.1 (no heading) → nav
   1.3. (no heading) → section (#main)
```

The first `nav` would be the navigation for the whole *page* (or the *site* navigation), as it belongs to `body`.

The second `nav` would be the navigation for the sidebar (!).

*If* this applies to your content, your example is fine. But it probably would only make sense if the sidebar contains other content in addition, otherwise there would be no reason to have a navigation in the first place. If you can’t find a heading (it doesn’t matter if you’d actually use it) for the parent `section`, than there is likely something wrong.

Without seeing your actual content, no-one can answer if your structure is correct. What is the `nav` in the sidebar used for?

- If it is a ToC for your main content, the `nav` should be a child of this main content.
- If it is a page/site navigation, it should not be a child of `section` (or any other sectioning element), so that it belongs to `body`.
- …

Answer (score 1):

If its a major navigational entity - then the nav tag is the thing to use. My humble opinion is that if you need to put nav elements inside section tags then its not nav-worthy. Not a major navigation.

The code:

```
<section id="sidebar">
  <nav>
    Go To...
    <ul>
      <li>First Move to Moon</li>
      <li>First Move to Moon</li>                    
    </ul>
  </nav>   
</section>
```

....could perhaps call for an aside tag instead of the section.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can use the button that looks like a {} to format code properly in answers - I've edited it for you for now though.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know special rules for positioning such tag inside or outside section tag, but I truly believe, that main purpose of semantic markup is seo, and that's why wherever you place this tag today's search engines of Google and others are smart enough to find it.